# How to control .localizedDescription of custom Swift error?

Tags: swift, inheritance, error-handling, try-catch

I have a custom error type in my Swift project:

```
struct RuntimeError : LocalizedError {
    let localizedDescription: String
    init(_ str : String) {
        localizedDescription = str
    }
}
```

If it is raised at the top level, I get a message like this which is useful but not quite what I expected:

> Fatal error: Error raised at top level: MyApp.RuntimeError(localizedDescription: "Error message…")

If I catch it and log its `.localizedDescription`, I don't even get a debug-like struct description but ± generic text instead!

E.g. the code

```
do {
  throw RuntimeError("Message")
} catch {
  NSLog("Caught error: %@", error.localizedDescription)
}
```

outputs only:

> Caught error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (MyApp.RuntimeError error 1.)

If I change my log to `(error as! RuntimeError).localizedDescription` I get the expected string, but that's not a solution since in practice not all errors will be of this type.

Why isn't my struct's `localizedDescription` property used when accessed through the `Error` protocol? How can I create a custom `Error` or `LocalizedError` struct that always provides a custom message?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using ObjC's error api's rather than Swift's?

Comment: @Alexander: There can be legitimate reasons to use `NSLog`. For example it writes to the device log, so you can inspect the messages later in Xcode. Also it is thread-safe (which `print` is not).

Comment: In this case, my reason was old habits when typing up a quick example for this site. In my actual code I have a wrapper around `os_log`; but my issue in question is with `.localizedDescription` no matter where it is used.

Comment: I figured it out, and it matches the duplicate question links as well: instead of an instance variable `let localizedDescription: String` I needed to store my message in `let errorDescription: String?` instead. Note that it *must* be an optional String otherwise it still doesn't work — I think that's what tripped me up when using other examples earlier.

Comment: @MartinR I meant subclassing `Foundation.LocalizedError` over conforming to `Swift.Error`

Comment: @Alexander: Then I misunderstood your comment! – But what are you thinking of as alternative? LocalizedError is a protocol as well (and inherits from Error), so this is not a subclass.

Comment: @MartinR Oh interesting. I thought it was a subclass of NSError. Nevermind!

Comment: Good question, I am faced with the same problem